# PHPUnit throws exceptions when there should be none

Tags: php, selenium, exception, phpunit

I am trying to set up testing for web application - I have Selenium standalone 3.2 server with VNC in Docker and PHPUnit 5.7.19.

However a line

```
$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath($main_button_xpath))->click();
```

sometimes throws (but sometimes it doesn't) an exception when it shouldn't - I have watched it via VNC and the target button was seen and was present on the screen and it still threw the exception. These errors started appearing since I have upgraded the Selenium server from 2.57.

Have you got any idea how to fix or debug it better ?

Thank you very much

EDIT : the exception

```
The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.2.0', revision: '8c03df6', time: '2017-03-02 09:34:51 -0800'
System info: host: 'dbcbaf52ae71', ip: '172.17.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.JUP1ydgC8zCR, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, page load=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=52.0, platformVersion=3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64, moz:processID=17210, browserName=firefox, platformName=linux}]
Session ID: 47bf2157-c7a8-47ea-a82a-3ab3ddd0ee61
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the actual exception message and the stack trace?

Comment: @segFault added the exception

Answer (score 0):

did you try doing smth like this?

```
$wait = new \Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverWait($driver, 5, 250);
$condition = \Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfElementLocated(Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy::xpath($main_button_xpath));

$btn = $wait->until($condition);
$btn->click();
```

UPDATE:

approach to do iterative tries could look smth like posted below. Still I believe this just **might** help depending on what is going on on the page.

```
$limit = 20; // might be different
$staleException = NULL;

for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++){
    try{
        // assuming $webDriver is ready to use and $main_button_xpath, too
        $webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath($main_button_xpath))->click();
        $staleException = NULL;
        break;
    } catch (\Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\StaleElementReferenceException $ex) {
        $staleException = $ex;
        usleep(250000); // 250 milliseconds wait
    }
}

if($staleException){
    throw $staleException;
}
```

and answering your comment: yes, I believe that there is no proper solution it the sense of smth clean and neat code. To avoid such kind of things we suppose to do have knowledge about these somewhat low-level details of what is going on with html and js on the page in order to understand what strategy of defense to choose. I do not think there could be another "universal solution" except for a bunch of strategies for each tricky thing (or tricky type of things, whatever) happening.

Comment: will try, but why is this happening ? It worked perfectly just before the update to 3.2

Comment: seen your update on exception details. I guess `wait` capability will not solve the issue. Looks like it does find the element but thereafter looses it. Any complicated JS on the page?

Comment: i see. something might happen to the element in between of retrieving its reference and actual clicking because of some js activity (detaching, moving or anything like this). If this is the case quick fix could be just to keep retrying for some reasonable amount of tries in a loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will keep that in mind. But from the way you put it it seems like there is no proper solution :) and is there a way to try it multiple times but still catch only the last exception ? (I have started learning PHP only recently)

Comment: please see the update. sorry it is a bit late, i could not  manage to get back earlier